# Can't get to @ViewChildren in parent component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-decorator

I am trying to get control over the children instances of a component and can't go past an error. I am trying to follow along the answers from [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32693061/angular-2-typescript-get-hold-of-an-element-in-the-template/35209681#35209681).

The parent component `Sequence` contains children components of `SequenceStep`. The parent contains the following declaration:

`@ViewChildren(SequenceStep) steps: QueryList<SequenceStep>;`

then I am trying to do something about the children:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.steps.changes.subscribe(steps => {
        console.log(steps);
    });
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> metadata_resolver.js:639 Uncaught Error: Can't construct a query for
>   the property "steps" of "Sequence" since the query selector wasn't
>   defined.

whereas both `Sequence` and `SequenceStep` components do have their selectors defined in their `@Component` decorators (`sequence` and `sequence-step` respectively).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, it took me a while to recreate the plnkr, but here it is: https://plnkr.co/edit/tusSBpbmyoG6TQTcV2i0?p=preview It is not working (please see the console) - the question is: is the code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things

- If you pass children from the outside, they are content not children. `@ViewChild()` only works for children added to the template of a component directly.

  `@ContentChildren()` works on transcluded content:

  ```ts
  @ContentChildren(TheChild) kids: QueryList<TheChild>;
  ```
- `this.kids.changes()` only notifies about changes after the initialization.
  Therefore just access `this.kids` directly in `ngAfterViewInit()` and then subsribe to get notified about later changes

  ```ts
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myKidsCount = this.kids.length;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();

    this.kids.changes.subscribe(kids => {
        this.myKidsCount = kids.length;
    });
  }
  ```
- Angular doesn't like when change detection causes changes. `ngAfterViewInit()` is called by change detection, this is why `this.myKidsCount = this.kids.length` causes an exception.

To work around I invoke change detection explicitly after changing the property `myKidsCount`:

```ts
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myKidsCount = this.kids.length;
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SvQ6deDBNrqoiifADsmH?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried adding quotes to your @ViewChildren arg?

`@ViewChildren('SequenceStep') steps: QueryList<SequenceStep>;`

Comment: Quotes are only for querying template variable names, when querying for component or directive types no quotes must be used.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be related to the import of SequenceStep, check the class name of the related import row.

Comment: Agreed. Also if you have a Directive (the ViewChild) that is defined in the same file as the parent Component, then the Directive definition must come first.

Answer (score 1):

`@ViewChildren('SequenceStep') steps: QueryList<SequenceStep>;`

Worked for me. Angular 4.X.X Angular CLI 1.X.X