# Ionic2: use getActive() to change button color for the active page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a nav component which I am using on 4 pages, I want to be able to change the color of active page's button in the nav component. In Ionic app doc's for nav controller I found getActive() instance, but I can't figure out how to achieve the desired result with it. I'm using the following code to push to a new view.

```
viewPage2(){
 this.navCtrl.push(Page2);
}

<button ion-button (click)="viewPage2()" color="dark" clear full>Page 2</button>
```

Comment: Could you please add some more code? Is it a custom component or just the default `ion-navbar`?

Comment: It is a custom component, literally a row of buttons.

Comment: Great, please take a look at the first option of my answer...

Comment: Thank you, I'm trying it right now I will let you know how it goes

Answer (score 0):

[`NavController getActive()`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/#getActive) returns the [`ViewController`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/ViewController/#contentRef) of the Active page.
Looking at the API of `ViewController` you could try using `getContentRef()`:

`this.navCtrl.getActive().contentRef().nativeElement.getElementById("button_id")`

Once you have the element you could change the color.

Answer (score 0):

Even though getting the html element by its id may work, modifying the DOM directly is not the recommended way to do things in Ionic.

---

**First option:**

If that's a custom component, you can always expose a public method in that component, and get the reference by using `ViewChild`

```
@Component({...})
export class NavCustomComponent {

    public activePage: string = 'page1';

    //...

    public changeActivePage(pageName: string): void {
        this.activePage = pageName;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And in your view:

```
<button ion-button (click)="viewPage2()" [color]="activePage === 'page2' ? 'light' : 'dark'" clear full>Page 2</button>
```

Then in the page where you're trying to modify the component:

```
@Component({...})
export class DemoPage {
    @ViewChild(NavCustomComponent) navCustomComponent: NavCustomComponent;
}
```

and then use that reference to call that public method:

```
this.navCustomComponent.changeActivePage('page2');
```

---

**Second option:**

If that's not a custom component, or you just want to make things even simpler, you can just [Events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/util/Events/). Whereever you're defining the code of that nav component, (or in your `app.component.ts` file to make it global for the entire app) subscribe to the event:

```
public activePage: string = 'page1';

constructor(public events: Events, ...) {
    events.subscribe('page:selected', (pageName) => {
        this.activePage = pageName;
    });
}
```

Again, in your view:

```
<button ion-button (click)="viewPage2()" [color]="activePage === 'page2' ? 'light' : 'dark'" clear full>Page 2</button>
```

And then in the component where you want to change the color, just publish that event:

```
events.publish('page:selected', 'page2');
```

Comment: I just tried it out getting the follow error `Can't construct a query for the property "navCustomComponent" of "Page2" since the query selector wasn't defined.`

Comment: I am adding the reference call in the constructor of the page 2, to me thats where it made the most sense `this.navCustomComponent.changeActivePage('page2');`

Comment: I guess that in the constructor the view is not yet ready. Please take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958199/cant-get-to-viewchildren-in-parent-component) and try by using in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle event

Comment: No luck, same error even after calling it in `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code to the question?

Comment: Sure here it is `export class Page1 {
  @ViewChild(NavcustomComponent) navCustomComponent: NavcustomComponent;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.navCustomComponent.changeActivePage('Page1');
  }
}`